# how can I get a hex dump from part of a hard drive?

Tags: command-line, data-recovery

I have a large hard drive, and I want to look at segments of it in it hexdump.
if I do `sudo hexdump /dev/sdc` It will read the entire device.. which isn't what I want to do, it will tank my system. I would rather read a few 512MB segments.  is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked man page for hexdump ? There should be options for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dd tool

```
dd bs=1MB count=512 if=/dev/sdc | hexdump
```